# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^n} dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate :$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^n} dx$$

My approach :

I tried substituting ($a^n + x^n$) as well as $(\frac{x}{a})^n$ with $t$ but arrive at a more ugly equation both ways.

Comment: Hint: Can you compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x)=1/(1+(x/a)^n)$?

Comment: I was doing basic integration tecniques like substitution and partial fractions when I came across this question. Have no idea of this technique.

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the question in my comment?

Comment: To answer the question in your comment, No. I cannot compute, because if $\frac{x}{a} < 1$ then the limit will tend to 1 or if $\frac{x}{a} > 1$ then the limit will tend to 0. So am not sure what the answer will be.

Comment: Well... you said it yourself: the limit is $1$ if $x<a$ and $0$ if $x>a$. This should give a precise idea about how to continue this...

Comment: I am really at beginning stages of Integration and can't understand how you want me to proceed. Please explain a little more, how do I proceed from here.

Comment: But you accepted an answer based on the "dominated convergence theorem", asking for no further explanation at all? What the...

Comment: Because I googled up Dominated convergence theorem and studied it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}=\int_0^a\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}+\int_a^\infty\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}$$
Now using the dominated convergence theorem with the dominated function (for  $n\ge2$)

$$\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}$$
we see that  the limit is
$$\int_0^a dx=a$$

Comment: I believe that your approach is more consistent with the spirit of the problem that mine. +1

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $$u=\left(\frac xa\right)^n$$ quickly transforms your integral to $$\frac an\int_0^{\infty}\frac {u^{\frac1n-1}}{1+u}du$$
This is a classic integral and it yields to the 'keyhole' contour to produce
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^n}dx=\frac an\cdot\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)}$$
So now you just have to recall that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)}{\frac{\pi}n}=1$$
So your final limit should be $a$.

Comment: Concise and clear. +1

Comment: Thanks, @Dr. MV. Incredible that you could read and edit my answer in seconds like that!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. ;-)) -Mark